# Python- Return true if all statements are true

Tags: python, boolean, boolean-logic, xor, boolean-operations

I have a method and I want it to return true if all 3 statements are true. In case any of them is false the method should return false.

```
def check_valid(self, a, b):
  
        statement1 = self.x == 0
        statement2 = self.y == a
        statment3 = self.z = b
        return statement1 ^ statement2 ^ statement3
```

I am using xor to validate if all statements have the same value but if all statements are false then the method will return true, which is not the intended behavior.

In order to fix this I am thinking in adding a true to the return statement like this:

```
return true ^ statement1 ^ statement2 ^ statement3
```

But I don't think that it is the best approach.
Is there a cleaner/better way to do this?

Comment: Did you mean to write `statement3 = self.z == b`?

Comment: I think what you're after is `return all([statement1, statement2, statement3])`

Comment: You could also use `statement1 and statement2 and statement3`

Answer (score 2):

This way would be a better approach and much more readable:

```
def check_valid(self, a, b):
    if not self.x == 0: return False
    if not self.y == a: return False
    if not self.z == b: return False
    return True
```